# numpy way to create 3-channel mask from 2d

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array scale_down representing RGB image (shape (500,500,3)) and mask 2d numpy array out (shape (500,500)) and need to fill all pixels of scaled_down where out is more than given value with grey color. Currently I do it the following way.

```
for i in range(out.shape[0]):
  for j in range(out.shape[1]):
    if out[i][j] > 10:
       scale_down[i][j][:] = 100
```

But I expect there is another way in numpy to do it without need in for loops. Any help with this?

Comment: Normally in `numpy` we index with `[i,j,:]` and similar patterns.  That `[:]` index does nothing.

Comment: @hpaulj Ok, thank you for the point. But I still hope to see implementation without or with minimal explicit loops usage

Comment: `scale_down[out > 100] = 100`

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser, thank you. That's what I looked for

Answer (score 1):

I repeat here answer provided by @Warren Weckesser.

```
scale_down[out > 10] = 100
```